# cannot run with sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Here it gives me this problem while I run the codes...

[the picture of the error](https://ibb.co/WyTbt8C)

and it is my dependencies.

```
 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  # carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  http: ^0.13.3
  get: ^4.3.8
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.0.0
  # google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.0
  # location: ^4.3.0
```

it is the codes, the first line of the library gives the error or let's say it is says unsend the import

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            items: [
              //1st Image of Slider
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage("")
                ),
               ),
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Click on main.dart the click Edit Configuration then in Additional run args column write
--no-sound-null-safety

or update carousel slider to

```
 carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
```